# How to add where in include properties in linq within a generic repository?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How to add where in include properties in linq within a generic repository?

```
public T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        if (includes != null)
        {
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include).Where("How to do");
            }
            //query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: why using generic repos a mistake ?

Comment: Because you are creating another abstraction; a whole bunch more work; future squirrelly design an architectural issues, with next to no gain (no matter what the internet, youtube or your instructor tells you). EF, is already a generic repository, and there are more appropriate patterns for ORMs

Comment: but how can i solve that issue now ?

Comment: @00110001 no, I am using generic repository in my own project and my lead developer didn't use generic repository in his project. I compare his project with mine. his codes are too much coding. around 10x - 20x work of mine. he did many projects his clients are very pleased with. my web performance is even faster than his. so i dont agree with what you said. I still prefer using generic repository as it can save my time alot.

Comment: I have added the code .after include I want to add where clause

Comment: Look up _entity framework repository anti-pattern_ to see discussion about this. To answer your question, look up LINQkit http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: IMHO using this method doesn't reduce the complexity of the caller enough to justify using it. It just makes the code harder to understand for a new programmer. Also, filtered includes are built into the include expression `.Include(o => o.Collection.Where(...))`.

Comment: Add to question usage sameple, with and without method, just plain Include with where.
Even i hate generic repositories also, the same functionality can be achieved by extension methods.

Comment: @Asherguru then both your code and his have serious problems, and both of you have broken EF Core. *Your* code though only works by accident. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit of Work. A DbSet is already a Repository. When you call `SaveChanges` you persist *all* changes. So your `Insert` may actually perform 20 deletes as well. Let me guess, did you add an explicit database transaction to bring back the transaction semantics you lost when you used a "generic" repository? How about the blocking and deadlocks caused by the long-running transactions?

Comment: @SumitRoy what you're trying to do is replicate what EF Core already does in a far better way. There's [No need for Unit of Work and Repositories with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) or any other advanced ORM by the way. ORMs like EF Core are higher level abstractions than the single entity Repository. What's *really* useful is a *specialized* repository, one that actually hides all those `Include` calls behind a method that returns a *specific* shape of objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't even mention about unit of work and repository. I only mentioned about GENERIC repository. I just simply do all select/insert/update/delete inside unit of work before transaction commit. Do transaction rollback if there is any exception. I don't see any issue. Just that using generic repository can save alot of time comparing to without generic repository.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your link you sent is wrong way to code generic repository. db.SaveChanges and transaction should be in unit of work, not repository.

Comment: @Asherguru but DbContext *is* a Unit of Work, not a repository. The *DbSet* is the repository. As for being the wrong way, this is actually the recommended way to work with ORMs since ORMs became popular in .NET 10 years ago. [Repository is the New Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) Ayende, the maintainer of NHibernate at the time, one of the people that created DDD and creator of RavenDB, is from 2009. BTW, what you call "generic repository" isn't even that, it's a DAO.

Comment: @Asherguru what about other critical functionality that's broken because a a low-level Repository was placed on top of a high-level ORM? You lost disconnected operations, the single most important scalability feature since the mid 1990s, when VB and ADO introduced disconnected recordsets. Once you use a database transaction to implement Unit-of-Work, you need a connection *and* a transaction active for a *long* time, blocking other connections and even resulting in deadlocks. You lose the ability to use optimistic concurrency. You don't even have a UoW, you're actively obstructing others

Answer (score -1):

```
var query = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
foreach (var property in context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations())
    query = query.Include(property.Name);

return query;
```

In Table

[image]

Show result data. TableA has all SubTableB and SubTableC data.

[image]

Filter your child class in controller or view.

[image]

Comment: It is working in my old project. what net core version you use? and you use EF core?

Comment: I use efcore . My problem is i want to add a where clause after include.like it should be  query.Include(property).where(condition);

Comment: you want to do where clause for parent class or child class?

Comment: I want to do for child class

Comment: You can do where clause for child in controller or view temporarily. I dont think it's possible to do it in generic method. You need to do it in its own repository if you want to add where clause after include. Anyway, I added screenshot above. it is another possible way if need to do filter for child. No worries if child has too many data. Include all (based on parent ID) won't affect performance.

Comment: This code (like all "generic" repositories) is trying to replicate what's already in EF Core. `Include` is already generic. `Set<>()` can't even be called before configuring a DbSet, so why not just use the DbSet properties? And putting this "repository" code in an *Action*, means the repository implementation isn't doing its job, with its internal implementation issues spilling into the UI code

Comment: In a controller action you *already* know what you want to load. *That's* the proper place to write `.Include().Include().Include()` to load 3 related entities. If you even need to do so - if the query creates a ViewModel, EF Core itself will automatically load all related properties. And code like `Model. SubTableBs.Where(..)` is simply a bug. It's the *action's* job to load load the data and send it to the view in the shape needed by the view. That entire loop belongs in the controller

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, this is just example to show him. GetFirst will be in BaseRepository. I won't use it in controller. By the way, without the generic repository and you have 50 tables, will you do their own CRUD in 50 repositories? 4-6 CRUD per repository = 200-300 functions? and for me, I only do 4 CRUD and 1 repository for all 50 tables. total 4-6 functions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "In a controller action you already know what you want to load. That's the proper place to write .Include().Include().Include() to load 3 related entities." This way, you need to create more and more function in repository to get what you want to load. For me, I just use 1 function for all controllers, no matter how many controllers I have, and I still don't need to create another function. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @Asherguru you have no tables, you have entities. ORMs deal with entities, not tables. And your assertions are simply wrong. You need **no CRUD operations at all** when you use an ORM properly, those are already provided by EF Core. You *introduced them yourself* when you used that "generic repository". Now that you blocked access to DbSet and DbContext, you have to keep aliasing their methods (at best) or reimplementing them.

Comment: @Asherguru besides, what do those "CRUD" method actually do? Just call the equivalent DbSet methods, essentially doing nothing? Or do they actually call `SaveChanges`, breaking UoW and the disconnected mode? What about that `GetAll` ? Does it return the entire table even when you just need 1 column from 2 rows? Or is it an alias for `AsQueryable` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Alright, can give me any sample project link or your sample project? I'll see how you do it and I'll also show mine how I reduce coding of yours by using generic repository.

Comment: @Asherguru you still haven't explained how you handle the critical problems created by generic repos. Never mind how much you increase code, that doesn't really matter if you end up with an application that crawls to a halt with just 3 concurrent users, or deadlocks with 2. Nobody cares how much extra code you added. They *really do care* if an e-commerce site crashes due to high traffic, or if they have to buy more and bigger database servers to cover bad coding

Comment: @Asherguru besides, the critical concurrency bugs can't be fixed with faster servers - if you use a database transaction, you block others no matter how fast the database or web server is. We're talking 100x-1000x better throughput and performance here, not 50% or "only on Amazon"